# ScreenToWorldPoint: How much depth has to be added to screen point?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation

I am developing a 3rd Person Controller.

The hero's chest should be rotated towards a point on the screen.

To determine the point, I use the following code:

```
var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
mousePos.z = 10; // Make sure to add some "depth" to the screen point 

var aim = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
```

Then I rotate the chest like this:

```
Vector3 v = new Vector3(0, aim.x, 0);
Chest.Rotate(v);
```

It does work, but it rotates only minimally, and the the direction is inverted:  If the mouse is on the right of the screen, the chest rotates to the left and vice versa.

Also, I'm not sure how to include the model's overall rotation (but I don't know yet if that is necessary).

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
When I add more depth to it, it rotates much more:

```
var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
mousePos.z = 100; // Make sure to add some "depth" to the screen point 

var aim = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
```

But I have no idea how much depth is actually needed.
If I add 1000, it rotates like crazy.

So I would like to know how to calculate the amount of depth that should actually be added to the screen point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Z you are assigning is taken as the distance of the point along the ray produced in the viewport; which corresponds to all the world points stacked on that screen point. The higher the Z, the farther it is from the camera.

That being said, based on the information you provided, I suspect you want to use `ScreenPointToRay` here, perform a raycast, then rotate the chest towards the hit point of the raycast. If the ray doesn't hit anything, then you can use your current method and assign a very high Z value to simulate infinity along the ray.

I'm also not sure what the purpose of just taking the x axis of your `aim` vector is. Don't you want to use the `aim` vector you already have? Why discard other axes? Also why are you assigning the x of aim to the y of your rotation vector? Maybe you want [LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you! You made a great point regarding the raycast. I forgot that the amount of rotation is dependend on the depth! You ask why I discard the other values of aim: The up / down rotation is done using a blend tree. Your answer made me doubt if my approach is right (and I doubt it now). I think you have answered the question perfectly I understand the problem now. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have tried LookAt before, and it was really strange. I tried to discard the up / down axis, but it rotated the chest in a strange way. I talked about that in a previous version of this question. I guess I will restore this version as a new question.

Comment: @tmighty Discarding axes might not be what you want, because that defeats the whole purpose of getting a target world point to look at in the first place. Hard to answer in more detail with current info, maybe you should open another question regarding how to use lookAt and blend trees together. I am not very knowledgeable in blend trees, but I am sure someone else will be able to answer it.